# Highchart areaspline gradient color not spreading uniformly

Tags: highcharts

My chart: https://jsfiddle.net/qsexy0md/1/

It is white on the sides at the start, end point of chart and no gradient at the middle peaks. I am looking for a way to show gradient uniformly throughout the area. Maybe an outer white shadow along the curves will do or any kind of gradient.

```
 color: {
                  linearGradient: {
                    x1: 0,
                    x2: 0,
                    y1: 0,
                    y2: 1
                  },
                  stops: [
                    [0, '#993989'],
                    [1, '#ffffff']
                  ]
                }
```

Comment: It appears as one would expect it to appear. From the smallest Y value to largest Y value. It is not clear to me how you want it to look. Could you supply an image or similar of what you are after?

Comment: @ewolden Sorry I don't have image for the desired result. I just need the white glow to spread throughout as one can see there is no gradient at the center/peak of chart.but at the lower parts it is much more visible. I just need that white glow contstant along the curve every where same height. I am thinking to put a shadow on lines.

Comment: Unfortunately, the way you want to make it is not supported in Highcharts. There is only linearGradient and radialGradient as you can check here: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.GradientColorObject. Shadow on lines will not make it also.